# Is it possible to get the list of the page I created and I dont have to be the fan of the page

Tags: facebook

I tried different way but it looks that I have to be the fan of the page in order to get the page list even I am the admin and I can post message inside facebook.

I had tried 
 http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.get
 and
 wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Pages.getInfo

Comment: @Robert, I do not think you need to be a fan in a page which you're its creator or administrator. Could you be more specific with your question? It is hard to understand...

Comment: Thanks Chris, I can make it more specific for this:
  In the link I posted on the original post, there is a sentence in the facebook api Pages.getInno wiki: "Returns all visible Facebook Pages to the filters specified. This may be used to find all Pages of which a user is a fan, or to query specific Page IDs." 

I tried the Stream.get as well, but I can only get the pages which I am a fan of it. 

I hope I explain the things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it myself that Fql can do this job. Thanks for Everyone.SELECT page_id,name FROM page WHERE page_id in (SELECT page_id from page_admin where uid=$uid);